# convert 2D ArrayList<Double> to 2D array of double

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How I can convert a 2D `ArrayList` of double to a 2D array double ? 
I create a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` and I want to convert into a `double [][]`

I try this but the last line doesn't work and I don't know why?

```
double data[][] = new double [datalist.size()][];

    for (int i = 0; i < datalist.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Double> row = datalist.get(i);
        data[i] = row.toArray(new double[row.size()]);
    }
```

datalist is my 2D ArrayList , and I have an error with `toArray()`
can you explain me why ?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Double data[][] = new Double [datalist.size()][];

for (int i = 0; i < datalist.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<Double> row = datalist.get(i);
    data[i] = row.toArray(new Double[row.size()]);
}
```